# Serial To Excel VBA without MSCOMM

Tags: vba, excel, serial-port

I am trying to pull data from a measurement device with an RS232 output. I am unable to use MSCOMM due to restrictions.

I have read multiple forums referencing the following two posts:
   1. http://www.thescarms.com/vbasic/commio.aspx
   2. http://dev.emcelettronica.com/serial-port-communication-in-excel-vba

The first link is a little over my head and I am getting errors during the try catch portion when receiving data.

The second link does not seem to work anymore.

Does anyone have a good recommendation?

Thank you.

Comment: What exceptions are you getting from your code?

Answer (score 1):

The longstanding classic solution for such applications is TalTech's [WinWedge](http://www.taltech.com/winwedge) I believe.

(We are not affiliated, rather the opposite. But I believe our own Docklight DLL would be oversized for this. Still, if you want, you can add an example RS232 data sequence from your device to this post here, and I can maybe put together a free example script for a MSExcel table import or at least a .csv file generator).